# Where can i set the tax classes?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, tax, tax-class

i have a problem with the Magento CE 1.9. I can't find the field or option for the custom tax class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it with the MageSetup extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can view your tax classes under:

System -> Config -> (sales) Tax

Tax is a subset of Sales but it is on the main left navigation

[image]

Comment: ok I have everything set but the taxes are not calculated or displayed.

Comment: Even in the default theme? Are you sure you don't have special rules or your user or product is not tax except?

Comment: Yes in the new rwd responsive theme.